# Removing character from variable in BASH script

Tags: bash, variables, grep, salt-stack

I have a script which utilises SaltStack's command-line as well as BASH commands. The script is used to gather data from multiple Linux servers (hence SaltStack), one of the checks which I would like to gather is disk space.

I have done this by using the following command:

```
salt $i cmd.run 'df -Ph / | tail -n1 | awk '"'"'{ print $4}'"'"'' | grep -v $i
```

$i = hostname and the use of the ugly '"'"' is so that my command can run via SaltStack as Salt's remote execution functionality requires single quotes around the command, if I left them in my command wouldn't run inside my BASH script.

Example syntax:

```
salt $hostname cmd.run 'command here'
```

After many questions on here and with colleagues I have this section of the script sorted. However I now the problem of stripping the output of my above command to remove the 'G' so that my script can compare the output with a threshold I have defined and turn the HTML which this script is piping to red.

Threshold:

```
diskspace_threshold=5
```

Command:

```
while read i ; do
diskspace=`salt $i cmd.run 'df -Ph / | tail -n1 | awk '"'"'{ print $4}'"'"'' | grep -v $i`
```

Validation check:

```
if [[ "${diskspace//G}" -lt $diskspace_threshold ]]; then
    ckbgc="red"
fi
```

The method I have used for stripping the G works on the command line but not within my script so it must be something to do with the syntax or just the fact that it is now within a script. Any ideas/thoughts would be helpful.

Cheers!

EDIT: Here is the error message I receive when running my script:
    serverdetails.sh: line 36: p
: 2.8: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".8")

Comment: why don't you strip  `G` in the long command itself? `sed 's/G//' <<< '10G'`

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj I was thinking about doing this and this is what I will probably have to do. However, I much prefer the webpage to view '10G' than just '10'. Yet the ability to change to red if the threshold isn't met is more important.

Comment: `disknum=$(sed 's/G//'<<<$diskspace);echo $disknum`

Comment: Does your script use `#!/bin/sh`? Change it to `#!/bin/bash` -- I believe that `${var//pattern}` is a bashism

Comment: Remove *what* "G"? You don't actually show the input string. If it's a *trailing* "G", then do `"${diskspace%G}"`. If you want to remove from the *first* "G" to the end of the string then do `"${diskspace%%G*}"` -- those will work in plain sh

Comment: Hi @glennjackman yes I am using #!/bin/bash - I'll give it a try, thanks for the comment

Comment: @glennjackman I tried "${diskspace%G}" to no avail. It still returned the same error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi Avinash, thanks for the comment. Just to be clear, where should I add this line? Is it a new variable? A change in my if statement  or my command? Sorry, I don't understand!

Comment: after `diskspace=...` , `disknum=$(sed 's/G//'<<<$diskspace)`, `if [[ "$disknum" -lt.. `

Comment: Thanks for the insight @AvinashRaj I updated my script with this and I still get the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error is coming from here (is this line 36?)

```
if [[ "${diskspace//G}" -lt $diskspace_threshold ]]; then
```

Note the error message:

> serverdetails.sh: line 36: p : 2.8: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".8")

**bash does not do floating point arithmetic**

```
$ [[ 2.8 -lt 3 ]] && echo OK
bash: [[: 2.8: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".8")
```

You'll need to do something like this:

```
result=$( bc <<< "${diskspace%G} < $diskspace_threshold" )
if [[ $result == 1 ]]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo Boo
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Glen - However this script will be ran daily and the available disk space will therefore change, will this method support this?

Comment: I do not understand your comment at all. Which method are you referring to? My hardcoded "2.8" was just to demonstrate the error.

Comment: @jto , yeah it should work.. What he does is, getting the disk space and then he compared it with the threshold (lesser than or not). if it's lesser then 1 should be stored to result variable else 0 would be stored. Error you got is mainly because of the decimal symbol in the diskspace value...

Comment: Thanks guys - I misinterpreted Glen's answer. So, I should change the $result == 1 to 5 so that it is my existing threshold value?

Comment: In `bc`, the result of the `a < b` operation is either "0" (a is not less than b) or "1" (a is actually less than b)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @glennjackman and thank you Avinash also. I just re-read my comments and I was clearly over worked yesterday, I've implemented your answer in my script and works fine!